# what is the purpose of the empty for(;;) loop in Random

Tags: java

I was looking at the java.util.Random class and found this:

```
private static long seedUniquifier() {
    // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
    // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
    for (;;) {
        long current = seedUniquifier.get();
        long next = current * 181783497276652981L;
        if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
```

Is there any reason for that loop to be there ?

Comment: To keep going until the CAS returns true?

Comment: @chrylis oh s*. I assumed the loop would run only once because there was no condition. so it's like a while(true). I should have test it but for some reason I didnt second guess myself.

Comment: There is no empty loop here. There is an empty `for` statement with no initial statement, while-condition, or increment-statement. Not the same thing.

Comment: in java8, this code can be rewritten as `return seedUniquifier.updateAndGet(current->current*181783497276652981L);` -- the meaning is more clear - atomically multiply the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `seedUniquifier` is an `AtomicInteger`, and the `compareAndSet` instruction is used to prevent thread collisions by verifying the expected contents of a variable and changing it in a single operation.

Based on the description in the Javadoc:

> This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor.

It looks like the purpose of the uniquifier is to help ensure that if two threads both try to create a `new Random()` at the same time, they won't both end up with the same seed value (and thus sequence of output); the `for` loop tells the constructor that if it finds a collision (the `compareAndSet` is false), then it should keep trying. In normal circumstances, it'll return instantly.

Answer (score 0):

`for(;;)` is an infinity cycle, which should contain `break` or `return` or you'll got an unreachable statement compile error.

Comment: well... dead loop is allowed in java :)

Comment: Infinity loop which contains no `break` or `return` statement is not allowed in java, okay?